# Execute code at CDI startup

Tags: java, cdi, bootstrapping

Is there a simple way to execute code just after CDI has bootstrapped ?

Actually I've got an `@ApplicationScopped` bean which I want to be instanciated just after CDI has bootstrapped, is there a simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few solutions but to me there's only two that does not feel hacky. I am not sure if Java EE 7 solved this somehow though, could not find anything when I googled.

1. Use `@Startup` from EJB. This is best if you can use EJB
2. Use the Servlet Module from deltaspike with `@Observes @Initialized ServletContext context`

http://deltaspike.apache.org/servlet.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm not in an EJB environment, I'm only in simple Tomcat with Weld providing CDI... I will try DeltaSpike's solution but I'm a bit afraid of the layers it adds (perhaps improperly).

Comment: Hi, Deltaspike is developed by guys from both Weld and OWB (and others) and it's not to be seen as an extra layer. Rather it provides more CDI functionality.

Answer (score 2):

From [this blog post](http://javaeesquad.blogspot.com/2015/03/getting-notified-when-java-ee.html):

> Only recently, with the CDI 1.1 version; may 2013 (Java EE 7); you have the possibility to receive a CDI event when the container is ready.

```
public class CDIStartup {
    public void postConstruct(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object o) {
        // CDI Ready    
    }
}
```

Comment: note that this is a synchronous call at startup. It needs to fully complete before the deployment is considered deployed